# How to create a NSIS installer with CPack without CMake

Tags: cmake, nsis, cpack

I would like to install several softwares at the same location.
These softwares are binaries and include files which are not managed by CMake.
My idea is to use CPack and NSIS generator but without CMake in order to just install the software at a user defined location and then launch a custom script that will create environment variable (under Windows).

Is it possible to do that with CPack ?
It seems that it can be done using a CPackConfig.cmake file, but I do not managed to define the directories I would like to install.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Seems to be some info here: http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake:Packaging_With_CPack

Comment: It does not explain how to define the directories to install (or I do not see where it is defined)

Comment: In you `CMakeLists.txt` you have to use `INSTALL(FILES "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/File/To/Install.so" DESTINATION
/usr/local/MyPackage/)` to specify where you want the file/library to install.

Comment: I do not have CMakeLists.txt files as I do not want to use CMake... do I have to create this file even if I directly use the CPackConfig.cmake script file ?

Comment: @oaimac did you ever find a solution to this? I have exactly the same problem just now and am struggling to find and answer.